# What does this mean, “Rick and Morty” references?

Tags: meaning

This phrase is from job posting site.

Nice to haves
Ability to recognize ***“Rick and Morty” references***
Familiarity with Wordpress
Working knowledge of Github interactions

Answer (score 1):

They are just being playful, saying tongue-in-cheek that familiarity with references to [this show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_and_Morty) would be a plus.